# Change URL Image when click on the button

Tags: java, image, jframe

I have a simple Java script here and it does not work.  I have an array with images from URL.  I want it to change when I click on the button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChangeURLImages 
{   
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    final String[] array = new String[]{"http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png", "http://indianraga.in/assets/default-bf4b832252a9579cf3408c88b2601a0e.jpg"};
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(array[0]);
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500, 600);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    JButton change = new JButton("Change");

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    p.add(change, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    f.add(p);

    change.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(array[1]);
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

I tried and tried.  Different ways, but I was not able to do this.

Can someone help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of a Label and doing nothing with it. You have to change the label that already is inside the container.

`label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));` instead of `JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));`

Answer (score 1):

In your event handler, you create a new JLabel, but the new JLabel is never getting displayed because you do nothing with it. It is not replacing the old JLabel which is displayed with the old image.

Change line:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

in your event handler to this:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

That changes the icon on the label which is already displayed.